# Ensure CSS consistency across all sites for notification injected by Chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension uses a content script (`player.js`) together with CSS (`player.css`) to put a notification on any site which meets certain conditions.

In `player.css` I specify styles for the classes used in the notification. The notification's `div` is styled `.notif` (there are further classes that style other `div`s inside the main `.notif`-styled `div`).

Problem: the notification doesn't appear the same across all sites - sometimes the underlying CSS of some site (e.g. Twitter) will mess with things like the default `a` class, the default `strong` class etc. So text might appear bold when it's not meant to be etc., colors might be changed, font-sizes too.

Even after trying solutions (below) I keep coming across sites where my notification appears slightly differently - I'm looking for a watertight solution that prevents this ever happening.

I've tried: 1) adding `!important` to a bunch of lines of `player.css` (which I know is generally a terrible idea) 2) adding a CSS reset to the start of `player.css` (I'm not clear on how to do this in context of Chrome extension CSS - when I added, it also overrode all the custom CSS I'd made).

What's the simplest way to solve this / what am I missing / if the answer is CSS reset, what's the most elegant way to do this in `player.css`?

(Note: I don't want to use Chrome's native notification API for this - need notifications to appear as part of sites.)

Comment: You could use shadow dom to encapsulate your notification and apply the styles locally

Comment: Thanks @juvian, by searching with keyword shadow dom I found the question which Xan just marked this as a duplicate to, as well as some other helpful questions. Think I'm OK now.